# HTTP 404 on invoking my WebAPI method

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

I'm trying to invoke my WebAPI method as defined below by using fiddler, but I'm getting the following exception. Please let me know what I'm missing here, as I'm not able to hit the method defined.

Method prototype:

```
[Route("api/tournament/{tournamentId}/{matchId}/{teamId}/{userEmail}/PostMatchBet")]
public HttpResponseMessage PostMatchBet(int tournamentId, int matchId, int teamId, string userEmail)
```

The method is defined within Tournament WebAPI controller and trying to access method with HTTP verb set to post as follows,

`http://localhost:59707/api/tournament/PostMatchBet?tournamentId=1&matchId=1&teamId=8&userEmail=abc@gmail.com`

Please let me know what am I missing here.

> Exception detail: "MessageDetail":"No action was found on the
>   controller 'Tournament' that matches the request."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure route configuration is done correctly.

```
public static class WebApiConfig 
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config) {
        // Attribute routing.
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        // Convention-based routing.
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultActionApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Make sure action has correct verb and route. You are mixing convention-based and attribute routing. decide which one you want to use and stick with that.

for this POST URL to work...

```
http://localhost:59707/api/tournament/PostMatchBet?tournamentId=1&matchId=1&teamId=8&userEmail=abc@gmail.com
```

it would match a convention-based route template like

```
api/{controller}/{action}
```

mapped to this action.

```
public class TournamentController : ApiController {
    [HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage PostMatchBet(int tournamentId, int matchId, int teamId, string userEmail) { ... }
}
```

If doing attribute routing then controller needs to be updated to...

```
[RoutePrefix("api/tournament")]
public class TournamentController : ApiController {
    //POST api/tournament/postmatchbet{? matching query strings}
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("PostMatchBet")]
    public HttpResponseMessage PostMatchBet(int tournamentId, int matchId, int teamId, string userEmail) { ... }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your URL path

```
http://localhost:59707/api/tournament/PostMatchBet?tournamentId=1&matchId=1&teamId=8&userEmail=abc@gmail.com

[Route("api/tournament/{tournamentId}/{matchId}/{teamId}/{userEmail}/PostMatchBet")]
```

As you can see you should end with the method according the route you set. Also you say that you anticipate separation by slash not as a parameterized URL e.g. (?, &). Thus it will listen to it if you pass in something like this.

```
http://localhost:59707/api/tournament/1/1/8/abc@gmail.com/PostMatchBet
```

Comment: the `.com` in the URL may cause an issue as it may be mistaken for a file extension.

Comment: I don't see how that would happen though, seeing as it's interpretation is set in the route combined with the method input it should already be told to be interpreted as a string. Could you elaborate?